# Python XlsxWriter chart with date axis - cannot set X axis format to date instead of text

Tags: python, charts, xlsxwriter

I have generated a spreadsheet using XlsxWriter 0.5.3.
The category cells are created using write_datetime() and appear correctly but I have two problems:
1. I want the X axis to be scaled by date instead of my entry so the timescale can be seen.
2. The X axis entries show the number of days instead of a formatted date.

The first can be done by manually changing te X axis format from 'Automatic' or 'Text' to date - is there a way to do it using XlsxWriter or isn't it supported?
The second is a problem because it becomes difficult for someone looking at the chart to go to the correct results. I have tried various solutions and it seems that a cell written using write_timedate() returns the nubmer of days only.

```
date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y/%m/%d')
worksheet.write_datetime(row_idx, col_idx, date_time, self.formats['Borders date'])
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of your question you can set the `'date_axis': True` option in [set_x_axis()](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027092330/http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org:80/en/latest/chart.html#set_x_axis).

See this Date Axis Chart [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925201321/http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org:80/en/latest/example_chart_date_axis.html) from the docs.

[image]
<sub>(source: [readthedocs.org](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_images/chart_date_axis.png))</sub>

That should also resolve your second question. If not post a separate question using the above chart example as the sample code.

Comment: Thanks - I would up vote but this is my first question.

Comment: Thanks, question answered.